# Validar un campo vacío en laravel

Tags: php, laravel, mvc, validación

Estoy intentando validar un campo en el controlador de laravel; la lógica es la siguiente, no es obligatorio poner información en el campo, pero si la ingresa información, quiero validar el contenido de esa información para evitar ataques XSS.

```
//Obtener los datos
$obtenerDatos = array('titulo_banner' => $request->input('titulo_banner'));
//Validar los datos
$validarDatos = \Validator::make($obtenerDatos, [
            'titulo_banner' => 'regex:/^[0-9a-zA-Z-ñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ ]+$/i'
]);
```

Esta es la forma como quiero validar la información de ese campo, y me funciona si me viene información en el mismo, pero si lo quiero dejar vacío falla.

Comment: Probaste agregarle la regla `nullable`?  `'titulo_banner' => 'nullable|regex:/^[0-9a-zA-Z-ñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ ]+$/i'`

Comment: Muchísimas gracias totalmente me funciono.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar la regla de validación [nullable](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-nullable)

> El campo bajo validación puede ser nulo. Esto es particularmente útil al validar primitivas como cadenas y enteros que pueden contener valores nulos.

Con eso, si el campo llega con valor `null` la validación pasará, y si el valor del campo es distinto de `null`, se aplicarán las demás reglas que le agregues.

Entonces, para tu caso, el código puede quedar así:

```
\Validator::make($obtenerDatos, [
    'titulo_banner' => 'nullable|regex:/^[0-9a-zA-Z-ñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ ]+$/i'
]);
```